# Table without date and Primary Key

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-web-services, teradata, datastage

I have 9M records. We needed to do the following operations:-

daily we receive the entire file of 9M records with 150GB of file size

It is truncate and loads in Snowflake. Daily deleting the entire 9B records and loading

We would want to send only incremental file load to Snowflake. Meaning that:

For example, out of 9Million records, we would only have an update in 0.5Million records(0.1 M Inserts,0.3 Deletes, and 0.2 Updates). How we will be able to compare the file and extract only delta file and load to the snowflake. How to do it cost-effectively and fast way in AWS native tools and load to S3.

P.s data doesn't have any date column. It is a pretty old concept written in 2012. We need to optimize this. The file format is fixed width. Attaching sample RAW data.

```
Sample Data:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dPpDx7VZ5g/
```

In a nutshell, I want to extract only Insert, Updates, and Deletes into a File. How do you classify this best and cost-efficient way.

Comment: You've tagged this for Oracle, Teradata, and DataStage but your question doesn't seem to indicate that you are using any of these three tools.  You've also tagged this for SQL but it's not clear that using SQL would make sense if you're trying to compare the data in two different flat files which is what it sounds like you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your tags and the question content does not match, but I am guessing that you are trying to load data from Oracle to Snowflake. You want to do an incremental load from Oracle but you do not have an incremental key in the table to identify the incremental rows. You have two options.

1. Work with your data owners and put the effort to identify the incremental key. There needs to be one. People are sometimes lazy to put this effort. This will be the most optimal option
2. If you cannot, then look for a CDC(change data capture) solution like golden gate

Answer (score 0):

CDC stage comes by default in DataStage.

Using CDC stage in combination of Transformer stage, is best approach to identify new rows, changed rows and rows for deletion.

Comment: There is no unique keys in my table. You may have seen the data in the question. Should I use all the columns if I do not have primary key column?

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify column(s) which makes row unique, doing CDC with all columns is not recommended, DataStage job with CDC stage consumes more resources if you add more change columns in CDC stage.

Work with your BA to identifying column(s) which makes row unique in the data.

Comment: To make row unique if you had to use all columns, then doing truncate and load is the right option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem what you have. In my case, there are no Primary key and there is no date column to identify the difference. So what I did is actually, I used AWS Athena (presto managed) to calculate the difference between source and the destination. Below is the process:

1. Copy the source data to s3.
2. Create Source Table in athena pointing the data copied from source.
3. Create Destination table in athena pointing to the destination data.
4. Now use, SQL in athena to find out the difference. As I did not have the both primary key and date column, I used the below script:

```
select * from table_destination
except 
select * from table_source;
```

If you have primary key, you can use that to find the difference as well and create the result table with the column which says "update/insert/delete"

This option is aws native and then it will be cheaper as well, as it costs 5$ per TB in athena. Also, in this method, do not forget to write file rotation scripts, to cut down your s3 costs.